# Parsing the text file in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My text file looks like this

```
 VOTE 1168041805 Campaign:ssss_uk_01B Validity:during Choice:Antony CONN:MIG01TU MSISDN:00777778359999 GUID:E6109CA1-7756-45DC-8EE7-677CA7C3D7F3 Shortcode:63334
 VOTE 1168041837 Campaign:ssss_uk_01B Validity:during Choice:Leon CONN:MIG00VU MSISDN:00777770939999 GUID:88B52A7B-A182-405C-9AE6-36FCF2E47294 Shortcode:63334
```

I want to get value of vote campaign validity choice for which I am doing this:

```
     File.foreach('lib/data/file.txt') do |line|
       line = line.tidy_bytes
       begin
         aline = line.match(/^VOTE\s(\d+)\sCampaign:([^ ]+)\sValidity:([^ ]+)\sChoice:([^ ]+)/)
         unless aline.nil?
             ## do something
         end
       rescue Exception => e
        raise " error: " + e.inspect
        p line.inspect
        next
       end
     end
```

Is there any better way for doing this for

```
      aline = line.match(/^VOTE\s(\d+)\sCampaign:([^ ]+)\sValidity:([^ ]+)\sChoice:([^ ]+)/)
```

and getting  aline[1] aline[2] aline[3] and aline[4]

Comment: Don't forget to use `\A` and `\z` in place of `^` and `$` in Ruby to mean "beginning of string" and "end of string" respectively. The second form is used to mean "beginning of line" and "end of line" which can result in wildly different results than you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [named captures](http://rubular.com/r/ZI7gwl0w2n) to get a hash of results instead:

```
# use a freezed contant instead of making a new Regexp object for each line 
REGEXP = /^VOTE\s(?<id>\d+)\sCampaign:(?<campaign>[^ ]+)\sValidity:(?<validity>[^ ]+)\sChoice:(?<choice>[^ ]+)/.freeze

File.foreach('lib/data/file.txt') do |line|
   begin
      matches = line.tidy_bytes.match(REGEXP)
      hash = matches.names.zip(matches.captures).to_h 
   end
   rescue Exception => e
     raise " error: " + e.inspect
     p line.inspect
     next
   end
 end
```

If the desired result is an array you might want to use `.map`:

```
# use a freezed contant instead of making a new Regexp object for each line 
REGEXP = /^VOTE\s(?<id>\d+)\sCampaign:(?<campaign>[^ ]+)\sValidity:(?<validity>[^ ]+)\sChoice:(?<choice>[^ ]+)/.freeze

results = File.foreach('lib/data/file.txt').map do |line|
   matches = line.tidy_bytes.match(REGEXP)
   matches.names.zip(matches.captures).to_h 
 end
```

Comment: On a side not - rescueing Exception is a huge anti-pattern. It will swallow bugs as it rescues things like NoMethodError. Only rescue specific exception that you know what to do with.